# Named functions in Bot Framework waterfall?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

The official documentation for the Microsoft Bot Framework [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-waterfall?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) show the waterfall model of a conversation using a series of unnamed functions, like below.

```
bot.dialog('greetings', [
    // Step 1
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
    },
    // Step 2
    function (session, results) {
        session.endDialog(`Hello ${results.response}!`);
    }
]);
```

But is it possible to instead use named functions here?

```
bot.dialog('greetings', [
    // Step 1
    greetingPrompt(session),
    // Step 2
    greetingMessage(session, results)
]);
```

I am trying to do this but having issues with the scope of the `session` variable.  Properties that get set within the named functions are lost in the outer scope, but when using the unnamed functions those properties remain. Is there a way to work around this or are we forced to use the unnamed functions? It seems like a messier solution, so I would like to be able to clean it up and reuse some code.

Comment: If anything, `s => greeingPrompt(s)` should allow you to inject a function calling another function, with little syntax overload.

Answer (score 1):

As Claus said, you can use arrow functions to clean it up, even if it is basically shorthand to change this

```
 function (session) {
     greetingPrompt(session)
 }
```

into this

```
(session) => greetingPrompt(session)
```

A quick example of what this looks like in action:

```
bot.dialog('/', [
    // Step 1
    (session) => choice(session),
    // Step 2
    (session, results) => responseResult(session, results)
]);

function choice(session){
    builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Which color?", "red|green|blue", { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button });
}

function responseResult(session,results){
     session.endDialog(`Hello ${results.response.entity}!`);
}
```